# Function with zero description

Tags: functions

Is there a nice expression (possibly differentiable outside $0$) for a function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following property other than the delta?
$$f(x)=1\iff x=0$$
$$f(x)=0\iff x\neq0$$

Is it possible to have something only in the numerator?
This is a great one $$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac1{x^2+1}\right\rfloor$$ but it has non-constants in the denominator. So does function using $$f(x)=\left\lfloor e^{-x^2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}\right\rfloor.$$

If $0<a<1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{n!|x|^{n}}$ works if $|x|>\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}>\frac{1}{n}$ and hence works for $|x|>0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: What is a *nice function*? What delta are you talking about? Kronecker's Delta?

Comment: Typically you'd see something like $\chi _{\{0\}}$,the indicator function for the set consisting of nothing but 0 for this, but Ajotaxe's formulation for this one is neater :)

Comment: You could also have $f(x) = \lfloor e^{-x^2}\rfloor$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 $e^{-x^2}=\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$.

Comment: All these are different expressions for the same function.

Comment: You use the word "function" when you don't appear to actually mean the mathematical word "function". You appear to mean something like "a nice expression for the function".

Comment: yes! all takes only $1$ as non-zero value. May be there are nicer ones (possibly differentiable outside $0$).

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac1{x^2+1}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Nice function!!

Comment: $f(x)=\lfloor \frac{1}{|x|+1}\rfloor$ also works for complex $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the value you wish such a function to have at zero.

I assert that, for most practical purposes,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \neq 0 \\ a & x = 0 \end{cases} $$

is the nicest expression for this function, barring the use of special functions, in which case something like

$$ f = a \chi_0 $$

is the nicest expression, where $\chi_0$ is the appropriate indicator function.

These may be boring, but boring is usually good, because that means they are very easy to actually use to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Without any special functions, and using only a single expression, you may say:$$f(x)=a\cdot0^{|x|}$$ where $a$ is the value you want for $f(0)$.

For all real $x\ne0$, $|x|>0$, so $f(x)=a\cdot0^{|x|}=a\cdot0=0$.

And consensus seems to be that $0^0$ should be considered $1$ (even though this causes confusion wrt limits, which is one of the reasons this is not (yet) universally accepted), which would make $f(0)=a\cdot0^{|0|}=a\cdot0^0=a$.